# Strange problems with streaming mp4 files on android

Tags: php, android, apache, mp4, lighttpd

Have realy strange problem with streaming mp4 files on android... on desktop all working fine

When i try stream files from **apache**

```
545161asd16.mp4
```

working fine..

but same files from **lighttpd** dont work, cant seek video..

but im just try rename file from

```
545161asd16.mp4
```

to

```
545161asd16.MP4
```

and working fine on both webservers and also seeking wrking on android

Can localte problem, if problem is android or problem is lighttpd and what's the difference between **mp4** and **MP4**

Comment: could be a matter of content-type declaration in lighttpd

Comment: Its a Content-Type video/mp4

Comment: Yes, my all videos have mp4 not MP4 ext..